# Exclude/Include or Filter dates from an array using React Datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-datepicker

I have an array of time slots. How can I filter only dates for rendering in React Datepicker? So, from this array, the calendar should active for dates 23.04, 24.04, 26.04, 27.04, 30.04.

Should filter by unique dates?

If I use **includeDates** prop in react-datepicker, it disabled changing month arrows.

Example array:

```
const arrayOfTimeslots = [
  {
    "start": "2023-04-23T22:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-23T22:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-23T22:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-23T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-24T00:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-24T00:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-24T01:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-24T01:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-24T01:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-26T00:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-26T00:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-26T01:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-26T01:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-26T01:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-27T21:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-27T22:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-27T22:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-27T22:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-30T22:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-30T22:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-30T22:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-30T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2023-04-30T23:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2023-04-30T23:30:00.000Z"
  },
]
```